# Read a utf-16LE file directly in cloud function -python/GCP

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a csv file with utf-16le encoding, I tried to open it in cloud function using

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO as sio
with open("gs://bucket_name/my_file.csv", "r", encoding="utf16") as f:
    read_all_once = f.read()
    read_all_once = read_all_once.replace('"', "")

    file_like = sio(read_all_once)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_like, sep=";", skiprows=5)
```

I get the error that the file is not found on location. what is the issue? When I run the same code locally with a local path it works.

Also when the file is in utf-8 encoding I can read it directly with

```
df = pd.read_csv("gs://bucket_name/my_file.csv, delimiter=";", encoding="utf-8", skiprows=0,low_memory=False)
```

I need to know if I can read the utf16 file directly with `pd.read_csv()`? if no, how do I make `with open()` recognize the path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, you can read the utf-16 csv file directly with the pd.read_csv() method.
- For the method to work please make sure that the service account attached to your function has access to read the CSV file in the Cloud Storage bucket.
- Please ensure whether the encoding of the csv file you are using is “utf-16” or “utf-16le” or “utf-16be” and use the appropriate one in the method.
- I used python 3.7 runtime.
- My main.py file and requirement.txt file looks as below. You can
  modify the main.py according to your use case.

**main.py**

```
import pandas as pd
 
def hello_world(request):
   #please change the file's URI
   data = pd.read_csv('gs://bucket_name/file.csv', encoding='utf-16le')
   print (data)
   return f'check the results in the logs'
```

**requirement.txt**

```
pandas==1.1.0
gcsfs==0.6.2
```

Comment: wow, I have tried this exactly before but it didn't work. And it worked now;) Thanks

Please update your requirements.txt with ```fsspec
gcsfs``` as well :)

Comment: Great ! Nice to hear it worked for you. I have included `gcsfs` in **requirement.txt** file.